# How to check if all elements of a numpy.array are of the same data type?

Tags: python, numpy

I have few numpy arrays, which can be formatted as

```
[1.525, 2.565, 6.367, ...]  # elements are float numbers
```

or

```
['', '', '', ...]  # elements are empty strings
```

I'd like to find out if all the elements in an array are of the same data type.

For now, I am using:

```
if isinstance(np.any(time_serie),float):
    return sum(time_serie)
```

But this one doesn't work. I got following error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

So, may I know how to work around this? Thanks.

Comment: You can check the `dtype` of the array.  If it isn't `object`, then they're all the same type.  If it is `object`, then you've got more work to do...

Comment: @mgilson's comment is better than my answer with respect to numpy arrays. My answer is a generic solution for possibly heterogeneous sequences.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a particular data-type as provided in your example, e.g. all items are floats, then a map and reduce will do the trick:

```
>>> x = [1.525, 2.565, 6.367]

>>> all(map(lambda i: isinstance(i, float), x))
    True

>>> x = [1.525, 2.565, '6.367']

>>> all(map(lambda i: isinstance(i, float), x))
    False
```

Comment: This can be greatly simplified to `all(isinstance(i, float) for i in x)`.

Comment: Agreed, all would simplify.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a list comprehension or `map()` for creating a sequence of data types, then make a `set` from this sequence and see if the length of the set is 1.

Comment: Arguably, there's no need to go through the whole structure, he just needs the answer, which is apparent at the first item which does not fit. `all(isinstance(elem, float) for elem in someIterable)`

Comment: That is right, but in his special case mgilson's approach to check for `dtype` not being `object` is still the most efficient shortcut :-)